# Update an array of objects with an array of updated values

Tags: node.js, mongoose, rest

I have an array of cart. I want to update the quantities of the products that is coming in the request object. i.e.

```
cart: [
    {
      quantity: 2,
      _id: 60757fdca818d96ed87c852e,
      productID: 101,
      vendorID: 60642991015028ba0a6ce72c
    },
    {
      quantity: 2,
      _id: 607584b4a818d96ed87c852f,
      productID: 102,
      vendorID: 60642991015028ba0a6ce72c
    }
  ]
```

I have an array of productIDs and quantitites like:

```
updatedValues: [
           { productID:'101', quantity: 3 },
           { productID:'102', quantity: 1 } 
         ]
```

I want to update them like:

```
cart: [
    {
      quantity: 3,
      _id: 60757fdca818d96ed87c852e,
      productID: 101,
      vendorID: 60642991015028ba0a6ce72c
    },
    {
      quantity: 1,
      _id: 607584b4a818d96ed87c852f,
      productID: 102,
      vendorID: 60642991015028ba0a6ce72c
    }
  ]
```

What can be the possible logic for this ?

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried, so we can better guide you to an answer.

Comment: I was not getting the result, so I don't have the code. What can be the possible solution for this ?

Comment: Please see How to Ask. This explains why you are not getting an answer. => https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well, you're right. I actually then figured out the solution myself.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
  updatedValues.map((product) => {
    cart.find((item) => {
      if (item.productID === product.productID) {
        item.quantity = product.quantity;
      }
    });
  });
```

Is there any other optimized way to get it ?

Answer (score 0):

So to update a prev. state array you could firstly loop through the prev. state and then item by item run a function which iterates through new array containing the updated values and find the specific item pointing inside prev. state of items and update them respectively. Here I'm using array's find function, `.find()` loops through array of updated values if it finds something it returns the found object otherwise `undefined`.
So, I think this might help you:

```js
  /* Here I'm assuming you already have original array coming from somewhere, inside results
 variable and updationArray represents the array containing updated information **/

const updatedResults = results.map((res)=>(modifyItem(res, updationArray)));

/* This function runs when we run the map function on results item wise **/
const modifyItem = (item, updationArray) => {
  const modifiedResult = updationArray.find(({productID})=> (productID === String(item. productID)));
  if(!modifiedResult)
     return item;
  return { ...item, ...modifiedResult }
}
```

So `updatedValues` variable should contain the array with updated values.